# Actions on Google launch custom action (not main actions.intent.MAIN)

Tags: actions-on-google

I have an Actions on Google agent built with DialogFlow with several actions (e.g. `actions.intent.MAIN` and `get_day_of_week`).

When I created my agent 3+ months ago, I could invoke the agent in two ways:

1. With the agent's name (e.g. "Talk to My Agent"), which would launch the `actions.intent.MAIN` intent.
2. With the grammar specific to an action (e.g. "Ask My Agent what day of the week is it"), which would launch the `get_day_of_week` action.

Without changing anything, launching the agent with a custom action (#2 above) stopped working. Is there a way to debug this?

In the simulator, when I type "Ask My agent what day of the week is it", the request and response are empty, and the dialog in the simulator says, "The agent returned an empty TTS". I'm not sure if the request and response are empty because the simulator doesn't support launching custom actions, because Actions on Google stopped supporting launching custom actions, or because my agent broke (even though I didn't change anything). For what it's worth, this same problem happened to two distinct agents that I have.

[image: Actions Console Simulator Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing there's nothing for you to debug; this appears to be a Google bug. I had the exact same thing happen to me on an action we have in production. There's no way I could have changed anything.

Here's [my Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleAssistantDev/comments/fxb2ku/deep_links_not_working/), if you wanna follow.

*Interestingly, the deep links don't work for me (and several others), but do work for my co-worker. And one of the commenters says deep links don't work for him unless he types it in the console.* ‍♂️